# use os execute to echo into a existing batch file

Tags: batch-file

So basicly I want to echo a output from os execute that I use in lua to a batch file that is already opened... So I tried to simply cd to the path I'll using and then simply with a && statement to echo it but it wont work,

any help would be appreciated

Comment: TBH, I'm surprised that this was migrated from the site, I'd recommend, in its current state, your post should reside!

Answer (score 0):

Although what you're asking for is possible, it is often error prone, and unreliable. (ie: changing a currently running batch file does work, but under some conditions, it won't work..)

Why not simply write the changes to another (perhaps volatile/temporary) batch file that the first one runs.

1.bat

```
@echo off
echo hi
call 2.bat
call 3.bat
echo bye
pause
exit /B
```

2.bat

```
@echo off
set /p input="Type something: "
echo @echo off > 3.bat
echo echo You typed %input% >> 3.bat
exit /B
```

> 2.bat could just as well be a Lua script or any executable that puts its output into 3.bat.